# Passing Large data.frames to Apply-like Functions Efficiently in R

Tags: r, loops, memory, parameter-passing

This is a question about resources and efficiency when passing large data sets to an apply-like function.

**Example**

[EDIT: changed example and discription to illustrate use of multiple tables and a calculation step per @UWE's comment]

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.5 ...[snip]...

set.seed(10)

# Objective: Add period-cost per portion of person's selected fruit 

df.A <- data.frame(
  period = rep(1:3, times = 1, each = 4),
  Name = rep(c("John", "Paul","Ringo", "George"), times = 3),
  Fruit = sample(c("Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple"), size = 12, replace = TRUE)
) # extend to many people, many periods, many fruit

df.B <- data.frame(
  Fruit = c("Pear", "Apple", "Banana"), 
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  pound.per.portion = c(0.396832,0.440925,0.299829)
) # one entry per fruit

df.C <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, times=3),
  period = rep(1:3, times = 1, each = 3),
  price.pound = c(2.33, 0.99, 2.15, 2.38, 1.01, 2.20, 2.42, 1.04, 2.25)
) # one entry per fruit per period

df.A
#>    period   Name  Fruit
#> 1       1   John Banana
#> 2       1   Paul  Apple
#> 3       1  Ringo   Pear
#> 4       1 George  Apple
#> 5       2   John  Apple
#> 6       2   Paul Banana
#> 7       2  Ringo  Apple
#> 8       2 George   Pear
#> 9       3   John Banana
#> 10      3   Paul Banana
#> 11      3  Ringo Banana
#> 12      3 George  Apple
df.B
#>    Fruit id pound.per.portion
#> 1   Pear  1          0.396832
#> 2  Apple  2          0.440925
#> 3 Banana  3          0.299829
df.C
#>   id period price.pound
#> 1  1      1        2.33
#> 2  2      1        0.99
#> 3  3      1        2.15
#> 4  1      2        2.38
#> 5  2      2        1.01
#> 6  3      2        2.20
#> 7  1      3        2.42
#> 8  2      3        1.04
#> 9  3      3        2.25

df.A$portion.price <- apply(df.A, MARGIN = 1, 
                           FUN = function(x, legend, prices){
                             # please ignore efficiency of this function
                             # the internal function is not the focus of the question
                             fruit.info <- df.B[df.B$Fruit == x[["Fruit"]],]

                             cost <- df.C %>% 
                               filter(period == x[["period"]],
                                      id == fruit.info[["id"]]) %>%
                               select(price.pound) %>%
                               `*`(fruit.info$pound.per.portion)
                             cost[[1]]
                           }, 
                           legend = df.B, prices = df.C) 
                            # Question relates to passing of legend and prices
                            # if `apply` passes df.B and df.C many times
                            # and df.B, df.C are large - is this inefficient, is there a better way

head(df.A, 5)  
#>   period   Name  Fruit portion.price
#> 1      1   John Banana     0.6446323
#> 2      1   Paul  Apple     0.4365157
#> 3      1  Ringo   Pear     0.9246186
#> 4      1 George  Apple     0.4365157
#> 5      2   John  Apple     0.4453343
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The objective in this example is to add a column to df.A that shows the portion cost for the fruit selected by a particular person in a particular period.

Three sets of data exist, though none of them alone have all the necessary information for the calculation.

`df.A` contains the people, the period and the name of the fruit they selected. An entry exists for each person in each period.

`df.C` has price information for the fruit by period, but the price is expressed as a price per pound, not portion, and the data set does not recognize names of fruit (only an id number). An entry exists for each fruit in each period.

`df.B` provides the missing information. First it defines `df.C$id` for `df.A$Name`, and it provides a factor to convert the cost per pound to a cost per portion. Only a single entry is required for each fruit.

For each row of `df.A`, `apply` passes the person's fruit name and period, along with the two reference sets (`df.B` and `df.C`) to the function. The function looks up the necessary infromation from `df.B` which it uses to reference data from `df.C`, which is then used to calculate a cost per portion (returned).

The function itself is not important to this question other than to illustrate use of multiple data sets to find a value for each row.

This example is simple (four people, three periods, three fruit) and very manageble with `apply`; however, each of these data sets could, in theory, comprise of thousands of rows.

**Discussion Topic Starts Here**

If I understand correctly, `r` passes values not references. I beleive that means that the `apply` function in the above example creates a new copy of `df.B` and `df.C` for each row of `df.A`. Assuming that is correct, this does not feel efficient, especally if the data sets are large.

Is there a better solution than `apply` for this sort of look up/processing when using large data sets?

I know `rcpp` functions can use references instead of values. Would one build a custom `rccp` function that acts like `apply` only using references, or is there a standard, off-the-shelf method?

Comment: Interesting question but, please, can you provide a more elaborate function where the answer can *not* be derived by a simple join. Have you looked at `data.table`? This might be a way to go because it was designed for large datasets. It allows to execute arbitrary code on the joined columns. It also has the `by = .EACHI` parameter which allows to join and aggregate simultaneously. However, I need to see a less trivial use case to understand your issue. Thank you.

Comment: @UWE - I added more details to the example.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. It seems that joining is a better way to go especially for large data.frames than using `apply()` which is more suited for matrices and arrays. Please, find more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `apply()` function with data.frames has a major drawback because `apply()` coerces the data.frame to a *matrix before proceeding* (see section 8.2.38 of [Patrick Burns' *The R Inferno*](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)).

As all elements of a matrix need to be of the same type *all* columns of the data.frame are coerced to one common data type.

This can be verified by

```
apply(df.A, MARGIN = 2, str)
```

> ```
>  chr [1:12] "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "3" "3" "3" "3"
>  chr [1:12] "John" "Paul" "Ringo" "George" "John" "Paul" "Ringo" "George" "John" "Paul" "Ringo" "George"
>  chr [1:12] "Banana" "Apple" "Pear" "Apple" "Apple" "Banana" "Apple" "Pear" "Banana" "Banana" "Banana" ...
> ```

Here, also the integer column `period` is coerced to type character. This is costly and probably creates a copy of all data.

---

So what can we do instead to achieve OP's goal:

> The objective in this example is to add a column to df.A that shows
> the portion cost for the fruit selected by a particular person in a
> particular period.

IMHO, the best way to achieve the objective is by joining two times.

First, a *lookup table* `lut` is created which contains the `portion.price` for each `Fruit` and `period`. Then, an *update join* is used to append the column to `df.A`:

```
library(data.table)
lut <- setDT(df.B)[df.C, on = .(id)][, portion.price := pound.per.portion * price.pound][]
setDT(df.A)[lut, on = .(Fruit, period), portion.price := i.portion.price][]
```

> ```
>     period   Name  Fruit portion.price
>  1:      1   John Banana     0.6446323
>  2:      1   Paul  Apple     0.4365157
>  3:      1  Ringo   Pear     0.9246186
>  4:      1 George  Apple     0.4365157
>  5:      2   John  Apple     0.4453343
>  6:      2   Paul Banana     0.6596238
>  7:      2  Ringo  Apple     0.4453343
>  8:      2 George   Pear     0.9444602
>  9:      3   John Banana     0.6746152
> 10:      3   Paul Banana     0.6746152
> 11:      3  Ringo Banana     0.6746152
> 12:      3 George  Apple     0.4585620
> ```

`data.table` was created to deal efficiently with large datasets.

---

Alternatively, SQL can be used:

```
sqldf::sqldf("
select period, Name, Fruit, `portion.price` from `df.A` 
  left join (
    select Fruit, period, 
      `pound.per.portion` * `price.pound` as `portion.price` from `df.B`  
      join `df.C` using(id) 
       ) using(period, Fruit)
")
```

> ```
>    period   Name  Fruit portion.price
> 1       1   John Banana     0.6446323
> 2       1   Paul  Apple     0.4365157
> 3       1  Ringo   Pear     0.9246186
> 4       1 George  Apple     0.4365157
> 5       2   John  Apple     0.4453343
> 6       2   Paul Banana     0.6596238
> 7       2  Ringo  Apple     0.4453343
> 8       2 George   Pear     0.9444602
> 9       3   John Banana     0.6746152
> 10      3   Paul Banana     0.6746152
> 11      3  Ringo Banana     0.6746152
> 12      3 George  Apple     0.4585620
> ```

Note that some table and column names are enclosed in backticks because periods have a special meaning in SQL

Comment: Thanks @UWE - Reviewing the `setDT` documentation, I see this solution directly addresses my concern about copying of data sets. *"In data.table parlance, all set\* functions change their input by reference. That is, no copy is made at all, other than temporary working memory, which is as large as one column."*